# Configure one django app on seperate domain and rest on other and need to share data between apps

Tags: django, django-sites

How can i configure a separate domain for one app and another domain rest of the apps. I tried using django sites, django-host. Please share the example

Answer (score 0):

Let there be 2 domains `main.example.com` and `rest.example.com`, and the application `main_app` is to be hosted on `main.example.com` and the rest of the application on `rest.example.com`.

```py
# project/hosts.py

from django_hosts import patterns, host


host_patterns = patterns('',
                         host('main', 'main_app.urls', name='main'),
                         host('rest', 'project.urls', name='rest'),
                         )
```

Considering that the rest of the application URLs is on `project.urls`.

Comment: Consider the fact that `django_hosts` only helps in choosing subdomain.

Comment: I need two seprate domains. App1 domain - app1.com, App2 domain - app2.com